# Unable to convert to Int from String

Tags: java, arraylist, string-formatting, permutation, parseint

I am working on a solution to the TSP problem. I have generated all the permutations of the `String` "123456", however, I need to convert this into an `ArrayList` of `Integer` like this [1,2,3,4,5,6]...[6,5,4,3,2,1]. I then store this into an `ArrayList` of `ArrayLists`. Once there I will be able to compare all of the cities that need to be traveled to.

When I run my code, I have a method to generate the permutation, then a method to change that permutation into an `ArrayList` of `Integer`. When I convert them, I get the exception `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""`. I don't know of any other way to get the `String` to `Integer`

Here is my code.

```
public static String permute(String begin, String string){
    if(string.length() == 0){
        stringToIntArray(begin+string);
        return begin + string + " ";

    }
    else{
        String result = "";
        for(int i = 0; i < string.length(); ++i){
            String newString = string.substring(0, i)  + string.substring(i+1, string.length());;
            result += permute(begin + string.charAt(i), newString);
        }
        stringToIntArray(result);
        return result;


    }
}

public static void stringToIntArray(String s){
    ArrayList<Integer> perm = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    String [] change = s.split("");
    for(int i = 0; i < 7; ++i){
        int integer = Integer.parseInt(change[i]);
        System.out.println(integer);
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    permute("", "123456");
}
```

Comment: you don't need to split anything. Just convert each char of the string to an int and put it in the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `split` method, when splitting on `""`, produces an empty string as the first element of the array, so you need to start iterating from i = 1.

Also, it would be safer to stop the iteration at `change.length` to make sure you process all characters when there are more than 6, and don't go out of bounds if there are fewer.

```
String [] change = s.split("");
for(int i = 1; i < change.length; ++i){ // ignore first element
    int integer = Integer.parseInt(change[i]);
    System.out.println(integer);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

These lines

```
String [] change = s.split("");
for(int i = 0; i < 7; ++i){
    int integer = Integer.parseInt(change[i]);
    System.out.println(integer);
}
```

Given a `String` like "12345", when you split it on nothing, it will separate every character. Giving you an array with `["","1","2","3","4","5"]`. Since the empty `String` `""` is not a Number, you will get the `NumberFormatException`. You could change your index `i` to start at `1` so as to ignore that first empty `String`.

Comment: Wow, makes since now, changed the for loop to start at one, and it compiles, thank you!

Comment: Np, if any of the answers helped you, you can upvote and accept when time permits. Good luck!